# Gnome terminal server errror

Tags: 17.04, gnome-terminal, crash

I have such error on Ubuntu 17.04 occasionally. I recently upgraded all packages, so their versions seems to be latest. Here are screenshots of up and bottom of error window:

[image]

[image]

I run it on Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

I see the Xubuntu mouse in your question. Maybe it would work for you with `xfce4-terminal` instead of `gnome-terminal`.

[image]

An alternative is to install `lxterminal` of Lubuntu or some other terminal emulator, for example `sakura` or `terminator`.

Comment: I run not Xubuntu but manually installed xfce on stock Ubuntu. You suggest to use xfce terminal instead of gnome? Can I remove Gnome-terminal without any consequences?

Comment: I am not sure that you can remove Gnome-terminal without any consequences. But it does not make any harm, if you keep it. The size is rather small.

Comment: However, if I keep it, the error won't disappear and will irritate me more and more:) The question is not to find a replacement for gnome-terminal, but to get rid of error.

Comment: The error and error message could be caused by a conflict between Ubuntu's standard desktop environment (Unity) and the manually installed XFCE. I'm sorry, but I don't know how to get rid of it without a risk to damage something.

Comment: @Suncatcher, If you think that my answer may descrease the chance to get a solution to the problem with the error and error message, I can remove it. Just tell me, and I will remove my answer.